# Need some correction with explanation below code

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x;
        if (x < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The number is negative");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The number is postive");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Value of a is : {0}", x);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

getting the error Use of unassigned local variable 'x'.

so  help me with this with please help me out of this

Comment: thanks very helpful

Comment: If it was helpful please accept it as answer

Answer (score 2):

You never assign `x` a value before checking its value in the `if`.
Assign an explicit initial value like `int x = 0;`